# preg_replace \n not between <script> </script> tag

Tags: regex, preg-replace

How to do this in `$string`:

```
preg_replace("~\r\n~i","",$string)
```

But not between `<script> </script>`

Comment: [By using a DOM parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) and applying the replacement only to non-`script` nodes.

Comment: why would it matter if you replace line-feeds in the script? In general it shouldn't matter; javascript code is commonly minified by removing white space.

Comment: @Spudley some people like to omit semicolons in JS.

Comment: @m.buettner - they shouldn't, but that's a whole different discussion. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to take the `<script>` tag into a subpattern and insert it again. In this way we safe it from being touched.

```
preg_replace('~\r\n|(<script>.*?</script>)~s', '$1', $str);
```

The `~s` modifier is needed that `.` matches newlines too.

Credits for the simplified pattern goes to @m.buettner from the comments.

Comment: @PetrNovotný What do you mean? Does this second version work for you?

Comment: Note that this does not help if the input starts with a script tag on the first line. I'd rather do `\r\n|(<script>.*?</script>)` and replace that with `$1`. This will skip over any script tags and remove all other line breaks it finds.

Comment: @m.buettner Your pattern is simpler and works better. I hope it is okay if I adopt in in the answer.

Comment: What if there's a `\n` that's not preceded by `\r`?  Or `\r` not followed by `\n`?  All three forms are valid.  Since you're deleting them all, I recommend you use `[\r\n]+` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: @AlanMoore unless you know your input contains only Windows line breaks (in which case your approach still wouldn't harm, of course).